# how to delete a row in grid attribute table of a raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, attribute-table

How can I delete a row in a raster file table? The raster format is GRID
I get this error "grid attribute table is blocked from deletion".

It seems absurd that I am not able to manipulate my own file. I am on ArcGIS 10.2 and the delete rows tool only works with shapefiles.

edit: my ultimate goal is to have a raster that only contains the pixel types I want to select and keep the attribute table intact, because I will need to use this raster for other operations.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot directly delete a row in a raster attribute table.  This is because deleting a row would essentially be reclassifying the cells in that grid to `NoData` within the attribute table, which is not supported in ArcGIS.

ArcGIS has a variety of tools to *effectively* "delete rows" including (to name a few) [Reclassify](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000sr000000) and [Con](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z00000005000000).  These tools actually replace certain values with user specified values, which can be `NoData` in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have tried both tools but I am unhappy with the outcome. With both I lose all the other fields in the attribute table. Reclassify throws a warning that "input raster max is out of range" and Con does not accept nodata as a new value, I tried to enter -32768 but it just replaces that in the new raster and the entry appears in the table as a regular value. I might have to try R, unless someone has a better solution.

Comment: @user4050 What is your ultimate goal?  Why do you want to delete rows in the attribute table?  Is there another way to state what you are doing--for example, you are trying to convert land cover classes with a value of 11 to NoData?  Thanks for the additional information.